# Reading a pointer from XML without being sure the relevant Obj-C instance exists

Tags: objective-c, xml, pointers

I have a "parent" Obj-C object containing (in a collection) a bunch of objects whose instance variables point to one another, possibly circularly (fear not, no retaining going on between these "siblings"). I write the parent object to XML, which of course involves (among other things) writing out its "children", in no particular order, and due to the possible circularity, I replace these references between the children with unique IDs that each child has.

The problem is reading this XML back in... as I create one "child", I come across an ID, but there's no guarantee the object it refers to has been created yet. Since the references are possibly circular, there isn't even an order in which to read them that solves this problem.

What do I do? My current solution is to replace (in the actual instance variables) the references with strings containing the unique IDs. This is nasty, though, because to use these instance variables, instead of something like `[oneObject aSibling]` I now have to do something like `[theParent childWithID:[oneObject aSiblingID]]`. I suppose I could create an `aSibling` method to simplify things, but it feels like there's a cleaner way than all this. Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds an awful lot like you are re-inventing NSCoding as it handles circular references, etc...  Now, there might be a good reason to re-invent that wheel.  Only you can answer *that* question.

In any case, sounds like you want a two pass unarchival process.

Pass 1:  Grab all the objects out of the backing store and reconstitute.  As each object comes out, shove it in a dictionary or map with the UID as the key.  Whenever an object contains a UID, register the object as needing to be fixed up;  add it to a set or array that you keep around during unarchival.

Pass 2:  Walk the set or array of objects that need to be fixed up and fix 'em up, replacing the UIDs with objects from the map you built in pass #1.

I hit a bit of parse error on that last paragraph.  Assuming your classes are sensibly declared, they ought to be able to repair themselves on the fly.

(All things considered, this is exactly the kind of data structure that is much easier to implement in a GC'd environment.  If you are targeting Mac OS X, not the iPhone, turning on GC is going to make your life easier, most likely)

Answer (score 0):

Java's serialization process does much the same thing. Every object it writes out, it puts in a 'previously seen objects' table. When it comes to writing out a subsequent reference, if it's seen the object before, then it writes out a code which indicates that it's a previously seen object from the list. When the reverse occurs, whenever it sees such a reference, it replaces it on the fly with the instance before.

That approach means that you don't have to use this map for all instances, but rather the substitution happens only for objects you've seen a second time. However, you still need to be able to uniquely reference the first instance you've got written, whether by some pointer to a  part in the data structure or not is dependent on what you're writing.